# Why does my translation machine always output 't'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, neural-network, translation

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

input_texts = []
target_texts = []
input_characters = set()
target_characters = set()

with open('catalan.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')

for line in lines[: min(653, len(lines) - 1)]:
    input_text, target_text = line.split('\t')
    target_text = '\t' + target_text + '\n'

    input_texts.append(input_text)
    target_texts.append(target_text)

    for char in input_text:
        if char not in input_characters:
            input_characters.add(char)
    for char in target_text:
        if char not in target_characters:
            target_characters.add(char)

input_characters = sorted(list(input_characters))
target_characters = sorted(list(target_characters))
num_encoder_tokens = len(input_characters)
num_decoder_tokens = len(target_characters)
max_encoder_seq_length = max([len(txt) for txt in input_texts])
max_decoder_seq_length = max([len(txt) for txt in target_texts])

input_token_index = dict(
    [(char, i) for i, char in enumerate(input_characters)])
target_token_index = dict(
    [(char, i) for i, char in enumerate(target_characters)])

encoder_input_data = np.zeros(
    (len(input_texts), max_encoder_seq_length, num_encoder_tokens),
    dtype = 'float32')

decoder_input_data = np.zeros(
    (len(input_texts), max_decoder_seq_length, num_decoder_tokens),
    dtype = 'float32')

decoder_target_data = np.zeros(
    (len(input_texts), max_decoder_seq_length, num_decoder_tokens),
    dtype = 'float32')

for i, (input_text, target_text) in enumerate(zip(input_texts, target_texts)):
    for t, char in enumerate(input_text):
        encoder_input_data[i, t, input_token_index[char]] = 1.

    for t, char in enumerate(target_text):
        decoder_input_data[i, t, target_token_index[char]] = 1.

        if t > 0:
            decoder_target_data[i, t - 1, target_token_index[char]] = 1.

latent_dim = 10
batch_size = 256
epochs = 10
encoder_inputs = Input(shape = (None, num_encoder_tokens))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state = True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)

encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape = (None, num_decoder_tokens))

decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences = True, return_state = True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,
                                     initial_state = encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation = 'softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs, validation_split = 0.2)

encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape = (latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape = (latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(
    decoder_inputs, initial_state = decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] +
    decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] +
    decoder_states)

# Reverse-lookup token index to decode sequences back to
# something readable.
reverse_input_char_index = dict(
    (i, char) for char, i in input_token_index.items())
reverse_target_char_index = dict(
    (i, char) for char, i in target_token_index.items())


def decode_sequence(input_seq):
    states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)
    target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
    target_seq[0, 0, target_token_index['\t']] = 1.
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = ''

    while not stop_condition:
        output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict(
            [target_seq] + states_value)
        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        sampled_char = reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence += sampled_char

        if (sampled_char == '\n' or
                len(decoded_sentence) > max_decoder_seq_length):
            stop_condition = True
        target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
        target_seq[0, 0, sampled_token_index] = 1.
        # Update states
        states_value = [h, c]
        return decoded_sentence


for seq_index in range(5):
    input_seq = encoder_input_data[seq_index: seq_index + 1]
    decoded_sentence = decode_sequence(input_seq)
    print('\n')
    print('Input sentence:', input_texts[seq_index])
    print('Decoded sentence:', decoded_sentence)
```

Output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-03-06 16:37:17.569143: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fc6781e2ee0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-03-06 16:37:17.569165: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Train on 521 samples, validate on 131 samples
Epoch 1/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 1.3404
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3235
521/521 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 1.3269 - val_loss: 2.2806
Epoch 2/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3238
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3232
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.3226 - val_loss: 2.2743
Epoch 3/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3432
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3204
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.3192 - val_loss: 2.2671
Epoch 4/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3363
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3180
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.3153 - val_loss: 2.2586
Epoch 5/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2933
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3102
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.3105 - val_loss: 2.2467
Epoch 6/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3062
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3085
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3038 - val_loss: 2.2313
Epoch 7/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3044
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2919
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2947 - val_loss: 2.2081
Epoch 8/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2874
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2801
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2816 - val_loss: 2.1818
Epoch 9/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2862
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2708
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2670 - val_loss: 2.1564
Epoch 10/10

256/521 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2387
512/521 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2506
521/521 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2528 - val_loss: 2.1281


Input sentence: Wow!
Decoded sentence: t


Input sentence: Really?
Decoded sentence: t


Input sentence: Thanks.
Decoded sentence: t


Input sentence: Goodbye!
Decoded sentence: t


Input sentence: Hurry up.
Decoded sentence: t
```

catalan.txt contains the text of this structure:

```
Wow!    Carai!
Really? De veritat?
Thanks. Gràcies!
Goodbye!    Adéu!
Hurry up.   Afanya't.
Too late.   Massa tard.
```

Why I always get `t`? I thought it must be a translation of a sentence in English. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your `return decoded_sentence` is inside the loop, thus the loop runs only once. You have to un-indent it. Then you'll see more and you'll probably get something beside 't' and you'll be able to debug further.

Comment: @h4z3 Now i get:`Decoded sentence: tiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
`

Comment: What language is that? Sounds like a really cool mashup of other languages.

Comment: @DanielMöller https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_language

Comment: As a start, you need to up your epochs. Your loss is hardly decreasing at all

Answer (score 1):

As @Recessive answered in comments: increase epochs.

I tested with 1000 and it worked, without changing other parameters.

Also: by tweaking those other parameters, results get better with fewer epochs.

That means: the code seems correct after correcting the `return` inside `while`, as noted by @h4z3.